# In CSS , How can I filter span element depending on dynamic property?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I use span elements like button and I disable and enable it depending on bussnies condition using old JS code like this:

```
document.getElementById('lblChecks').disabled = false/true
```

in HTML

```
<span id="lblChecks" disabled="disabled" class="GridHeader" onclick="ChecksPoPuP();" style="display:inline-block;color:White;height:19px;width:132px;cursor: hand;">Cheques</span>
```

In CSS I use `.GridHeader[disabled="disabled"]` but it doesn't work on chrome, but it works fine on IE.

So how can I filter (.disabled) as dynamic property in CSS

Note: the problem can be solved easily using addClass and removeClass in JQuery but I have a lot of files and its hard to replace all of them

Answer (score 2):

You can define a common class name for all the elements which is disabled/enabled back and forth, and use CSS to style it.

For example:

```
.att-disabled:disabled{ // style goes here }
```

Refer more:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:disabled

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. it works only on input elements but I use Span

Comment: @MazenAj There is no `disabled` on `<span>` elements.